# map nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, nested-object

I have a nested array of objects like this:

```
let data = [
  {
      id: 1,
      title: "Abc",
      children: [
          {
              id: 2,
              title: "Type 2",
              children: [
                  {
                      id: 23,
                      title: "Number 3",
                      children:[] /* This key needs to be deleted */
                  }
              ]
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      id: 167,
      title: "Cde",
      children:[] /* This key needs to be deleted */
  }
]
```

All I want is to recursively find `leaves` with no children (currently an empty array) and remove the children property from them.

Here's my code:

```
normalizeData(data, arr = []) {
    return data.map((x) => {
        if (Array.isArray(x))
            return this.normalizeData(x, arr)
        return {
            ...x,
            title: x.name,
            children: x.children.length ? [...x.children] : null
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your efforts till now ?

Comment: added code, please take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use recursion for that:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Abc",
    children: [{
      id: 2,
      title: "Type 2",
      children: [{
        id: 23,
        title: "Number 3",
        children: [] /* This key needs to be deleted */
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 167,
    title: "Cde",
    children: [] /* This key needs to be deleted */
  }
]

function traverse(obj) {
  for (const k in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[k] == 'object' && obj[k] !== null) {
      if (k === 'children' && !obj[k].length) {
        delete obj[k]
      } else {
        traverse(obj[k])              
      }
    }
  }
}

traverse(data)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Nik's answer is fine (though I don't see the point of accessing the `children` key like that), but here's a shorter alternative if it can help:

```js
let data = [
  {id: 1, title: "Abc", children: [
    {id: 2, title: "Type 2", children: [
      {id: 23, title: "Number 3", children: []}
    ]}
  ]},
  {id: 167, title: "Cde", children: []}
];

data.forEach(deleteEmptyChildren = o => 
  o.children.length ? o.children.forEach(deleteEmptyChildren) : delete o.children);

console.log(data);
```

If `children` is not always there, you can change the main part of the code to:

```
data.forEach(deleteEmptyChildren = o => 
  o.children && o.children.length 
    ? o.children.forEach(deleteEmptyChildren) 
    : delete o.children);
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution

Comment: This will fail if there is no children key in object

Comment: I am just not a fan of the extra loop to initialize it.

Comment: @CodeManiac Well looking at OP's input, it seems like it's always here even when it's empty (that's why he wants to remove them to begin with). Code's easily adjustable though if that's not the case.

Comment: @CodeManiac `e.children && e.children.length` solves the issue so not a big deal

Comment: @epascarello I kinda like it more when the function applies to actual items, as opposed to a collection of items, especially if it's supposed to be reused in differenct circumstances. Matter of preference I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using recursion.

So here the basic idea is in `removeEmptyChild` function we check if the children length is non zero or not. so if it is we loop through each element in children array and pass them function again as parameter, if the children length is zero we delete the children key.

```js
let data=[{id:1,title:"Abc",children:[{id:2,title:"Type2",children:[{id:23,title:"Number3",children:[]}]},]},{id:167,title:"Cde",children:[]},{id:1}]

function removeEmptyChild(input){
  if( input.children && input.children.length ){
    input.children.forEach(e => removeEmptyChild(e) )
  } else {
    delete input.children
  }
  return input
}

data.forEach(e=> removeEmptyChild(e))

console.log(data)
```

Comment: why are you using map?

Comment: @epascarello oh my bad. i overlooked use of map here. thanks for pointing out best case to use forEach

Answer (score 2):

Simple recursion with forEach is all that is needed.

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Abc",
    children: [{
      id: 2,
      title: "Type 2",
      children: [{
        id: 23,
        title: "Number 3",
        children: [] /* This key needs to be deleted */
      }]
    }, ]
  },
  {
    id: 167,
    title: "Cde",
    children: [] /* This key needs to be deleted */
  }
]

const cleanUp = data =>
  data.forEach(n =>
    n.children.length
      ? cleanUp(n.children)
      : (delete n.children))
      
      
cleanUp(data)
console.log(data)
```

This assumes children is there. If it could be missing than just needs a minor change to the check so it does not error out on the length check. `n.children && n.children.length`